# How to change my function into an recursive one?

Tags: python, function, recursion

I have a dictionary that I need to convert as a SQL filter statement. This dictionary can be a nested one e.g.

**Dictionary**:

```
filter_dictionary_example = {'or': [{'and': [Filter('COMPANY','= CompanyA'), Filter('DATE','> 18/06/2022') ]}, {'and': [Filter('COMPANY','= CompanyB'), Filter('DATE','> 18/05/2022') ]}]}
```

**Corresponding SQL Statement**:

```
WHERE (src.COMPANY = CompanyA AND src.DATE > 18/06/2022) OR (src.COMPANY = CompanyB AND src.DATE > 18/05/2022)
```

I have code that converts this dictionary to a string containing the filter SQL statement. However, I have to call on the function 3 times.

Firstly, I have a Filter class which has properties field (SQL field to filter on) and expression (SQL expression on how to filter the field). Then, the function decompose_list decomposes a list to put the operator of the filter in between the conditions it corresponds to, but the function must be called more than once if there is more than one condition to be applied in the filter and more times if there are nested operators. For this example, the decompose_list function has to be called 3 times within the getSQLFilter function as there is more than one condition and the 'and' operators are within the 'or' operator. After calling the decompose_list function three times within the getSQLFilter function, the multiple strings along with a WHERE string is formed into one string which is the SQL filter.

Does anyone know how I can change the decompose_list function so that it is a recursive one, meaning that I avoid calling on it three times?

Here is my code below with the example that was used before:

```
class Filter():
    # properties: field (SQL field to filter on) and expression (SQL expression on how to filter the field)
    def __init__(self,field='',expression=''):
        self.field = field
        self.expression = expression

def decompose_list(list_of_conditions):
        sql_conditions=[]

        for i,conditions in enumerate(list_of_conditions):

            sql_conditions.append(conditions)

            if type(conditions) == dict:
                sql_conditions.pop()

                sql_conditions.append('(')
                for k,[operator,nest_of_conditions] in enumerate(conditions.items()):
                    
                        for j,element in enumerate(nest_of_conditions):

                            if type(element) == dict:
                                
                                sql_conditions.append(element)
                                
                            
                            else:

                                sql_conditions.append('src.' + element.field + ' ' + element.expression)
                            if j < len(nest_of_conditions)-1:
                                sql_conditions.append(operator.upper())
                sql_conditions.append(')')

        return sql_conditions

def getSQLFilter(filter_dictionary):
        """
        Get a filter SQL statement with the operators along with their associated conditions
        """


        filter_dictionary_as_list = []
        filter_dictionary_as_list.append(filter_dictionary)
 
        # where i call the function 3 times
        filter_as_a_string = decompose_list(decompose_list(decompose_list(filter_dictionary_as_list)))

        filter_as_a_string = filter_as_a_string[1:-1] #removing extra brackets that exist at the start and end
        sql_filter_unclean = 'WHERE ' + ' '.join(map(str,filter_as_a_string)) # creating one string from list of strings and adding WHERE at the front
        sql_filter = sql_filter_unclean.replace("( ","("    ).replace(' )', ")") # removing extra whitespace after opening bracket and before closing bracket

        return sql_filter

filter_dictionary_example = {'or': [{'and': [Filter('COMPANY','= CompanyA'), Filter('DATE','> 18/06/2022') ]}, {'and': [Filter('COMPANY','= CompanyB'), Filter('DATE','> 18/05/2022') ]}]}

getSQLFilter(filter_dictionary_example)
```

Answer (score 0):

**getting started**

1. You use `Filter` to construct some of your expressions, but not others.
2. A uniform expression type would make it easier to write a SQL expander (evaluator)

```py
def Or(*exprs):
  return ("or", *exprs)

def And(*exprs):
  return ("and", *exprs)

def Filter(a, operator, b):
  return ("filter", a, operator, b)
```

```py
filter_dictionary_example = \
  Or(
    And(
      Filter('COMPANY', '=', 'CompanyA'),
      Filter('DATE','>', '18/06/2022')
    ),
    And(
      Filter('COMPANY', '=', 'CompanyB'),
      Filter('DATE', '>', '18/05/2022')
    )
  )
```

```py
def eval(expr):
  (type, *args) = expr
  if type == "or":
    return "(" + " or ".join(map(eval, args)) + ")"
  elif type == "and":
    return "(" + " and ".join(map(eval, args)) + ")"
  elif type == "filter":
    return " ".join(args)
  raise RuntimeError(f"invalid expression: {expr}")
```

```py
print(eval(filter_example))
```

```
((COMPANY = CompanyA and DATE > 18/06/2022) or (COMPANY = CompanyB and DATE > 18/05/2022))
```

**quotation and sql injection**

But you need to be concerned with string quotation and SQL injection attacks. Consider returning a template string and values instead -

```py
("((COMPANY = %s and DATE > %s) or (COMPANY = %s and DATE > %s))", ("CompanyA", "18/06/2022", "CompanyB", "18/05/2022"))
```

Using the updated `eval` would look like this -

```py
(conditions, args) = eval(filter_example)
query = f"SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE {conditions}"
mycursor.execute(query, args)
```

This exercise is left for the reader.